# ASP.NET web development with C# : centralize the connection string

Tags: c#, asp.net, web, web-deployment

I am new to asp.net and C#. I am using a connection string in each and every page to connect to database and get results (the connection string is shown in the below code). Is there any way I can make the connection string centralized? So that I don't have to call it in each and every page?

Can anyone help me to solve this problem? please..

```
con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=localhost\\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=ewadb;Integrated Security=SSPI");

//data = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM deals", con);
//dset = new DataSet();
//data.Fill(dset, "deal");
```

Comment: do it in web.config file

Comment: The following links should help:
http://www.connectionstrings.com/store-connection-string-in-webconfig/
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178411.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put the connection string in the web.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
 <connectionStrings>
    <add name="default" connectionString="Data Source=localhost\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=ewadb;Integrated Security=SSPI" />
 </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

You can then get the value with the [ConfigurationManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class:

```
ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["default"].ConnectionString;
```

Architecturally speaking, your pages shouldn't be handling data access directly.

See here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multitier_architecture for overview of n-tier architecture.

Comment: thank you. Robh..

but when i try to pass the connection string in to newsqlconnection function it gives an error saying "instance failure"..

con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["default"].ConnectionString);

Comment: Whoops. Remove the double slash from connection string. I'll edit answer now.

Answer (score 2):

You should place it in the web.config. This means you can change it easily and call it consistently from anywhere. Please see the following for an intro.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178411.aspx

Also a simple explaination:

http://www.connectionstrings.com/store-connection-string-in-webconfig/

Answer (score 0):

1) Use `web.config` file for store your connection string as this

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="connString_MyDB" value="Server=localhost;Integrated Security=false;Database=WORLD;Asynchronous Processing=True;user=sa;password=123;"/>
</appSettings>
```

2) to retrieve the connection string call as this in your class

```
  Private connString As String = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("connString_MyDB").ToString
```

Comment: thanks amila.
but i need the value and pass it in to a new sqlconnection function. like this..

    con = new sqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("connection"));

is there any way i can pass  the connection string in to the function..

Answer (score 0):

Place the connection string into configuration section of your `web.config` file.

```
<configuration>
 <connectionStrings>
    <add name="default" connectionString="your connection string" />
 </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Use below code to access connection string in page.

```
System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.
    ConnectionStrings["connectionStringName"].ConnectionString;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that like below:

Web.Config:

Get the connection string in code:
sqlConnection con = new sqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("connect‌​ion"));